# gameobject object variable is not assigned, how do i assign this in script in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried to assign my prefab `Bridge` in many different ways.

I still get an error saying "variable of bridge in GameManager has not been assigned"

Is there anyway to fix this issue please, Would be more than happy an appreciative if anyone can help me out!

```
public GameObject Bridge;
public GameObject player;

public float spawnSpacer = 10f;
public float rightSpacer = 10f;
public float leftSpacer = 10f;

int spawnNum;

public float spawnDelay = 1f;

public List<Movement> bridges;

bool left;

private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(InitialSpawns), spawnDelay, spawnDelay);
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        StopBridge();
        SpawnBridge();
    }
}

public void StopBridge()
{
    if (bridges.Count != 0)
    {
        bridges[0].locked = true;
        bridges.Remove(bridges[0]);
    }
}

public void SpawnBridge()
{

    //Determine spawn location by manipulating player position.
    Vector3 spawnPosition = player.transform.position;
    spawnPosition.x += spawnSpacer;
    if (left)
    {
        spawnPosition.z += leftSpacer;
        left = false;
    }
    else if (!left)
    {
        spawnPosition.z -= leftSpacer;
        left = true;
    }
    //Spawn a new platform.
    GameObject newBridge = Instantiate(Bridge, spawnPosition, player.transform.rotation);
    if (left)
        newBridge.GetComponent<Movement>().left = true;
    else if (!left)
        newBridge.GetComponent<Movement>().right = true;
    bridges.Add(newBridge.GetComponent<Movement>());
}

void InitialSpawns()
{
    if (spawnNum == 5)
        CancelInvoke(nameof(InitialSpawns));
    SpawnBridge();
    spawnNum++;
}
```

}

Comment: Because its not....

Comment: can you tell which line exactly is causing this error?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://answers.unity.com/questions/627750/the-variable-has-not-been-assigned-but-it-has.html

Answer (score 0):

What is happening if you try to drag the object "Bridge" from the hierarchy to inspector in editor? if it is still not working then to set it via script use:

```cs
public GameObject Bridge = GameObject.Find("ObjectName");
```

alternatively, you can also use the tag of the object to find it:

```cs
public GameObject Bridge = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameObject Tag"). gameObject;
```